# How to call a SOAP WebService client in java 11?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, java-11

I'm new to java programming and webservices in general.

I have to create a SOAP cliente for a webservice that I need to use in my code, I have generated the related classes to the service using apache's cxf-codegen-plugin maven plugin, this creates a class that you can instanciate to call the service and then it's methods.

This works fine in java 8, however, when using java 11 (and I need to use it) its generates a nullPointerException when instanciating it.

I'm obtaining the generated classes from this wsdl: https://wsaahomo.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms?wsdl

`LoginCMSService service = new LoginCMSService();`

When trying to run it in java 11, it generates the next exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
[apache-tomcat-8.5.65-1]: java.lang.NullPointerException
[apache-tomcat-8.5.65-1]:   at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112)
[apache-tomcat-8.5.65-1]:   at com.xxx.afipinformationplugin.generated.loginWsaa.LoginCMSService.<init>(LoginCMSService.java:44)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

This was solved by adding the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version> 
        </dependency>
```